# Should I flag an "answer" that only points out the defects of another answer in some circumstances?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers

I was looking for alternative answers in a question, and [found it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25076323/4227915):

[image]

Is it considerated an answer? Should I flag it?

Comment: Ugh, It is *an* attempt at an answer, so the NaA flag is a no-go. However, there are some pretty bad content issues with that post (not necessarily ones that cannot be fixed with editing) I would hesitantly suggest the VLQ flag (and a downvote of course).

Comment: @TinyGiant I wouldn't even call that an attempt at an answer. It does not address the post in any way. Its an orange in the classic NAA post.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I would say that too.... but NaA flags are pretty delicate these days, and I could see where a mod (seeing no question as context) may see that post as an attempted answer to *a* question. The VLQ flag fits, and is much less likely to be declined.

Comment: @TinyGiant Or just "Other". Regardless, it should be nuked from orbit.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Most definitely.

Comment: If I were looking at flags on this post I would happily validate a NAA flag on it, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Did everybody miss his edit of the accepted answer?  Voting doesn't always cut it at SO, pretty hard to get rid of an outdated bad practice.

Comment: @HansPassant [I've rolled back that edit.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13609510/revisions) It was clearly an attempt to comment on the post, and should have been rejected by reviewers. :(

Comment: I wouldnt even downvote it because of that. I'd downvote it because it's an awful 'answer'.

Comment: I don't think it really matters how you flag it (not an answer or low quality) beacos it's weeery weery bad.

Answer (score 64):

Yes, flag it. It *clearly* does not answer the question. Such posts should go in the comments.

Note that an answer that points out a flaw in another **and then proceeds to answer the question** is still very much an answer.

Comment: Or, putting it in another way, if you remove the critic to the other answer still answers the question, then it **is** an answer.

Comment: Moreover, in that case, the criticism is probably useful as context to the answer.

Comment: Hmm. I wouldn't be quite as unequivocal as you are here. Remember that partial answers are permitted, and "you can't do this, it's impossible" answers are permitted. I'd argue that an answer which explores a likely approach to the problem and demonstrates why it fails can be a legitimate partial answer. If such an answer is detailed, contains real insight that helps me understand the problem better, and is long enough that it couldn't reasonably have been put in a comment, then I definitely wouldn't flag. (Though that's not true of the crappy answer being discussed here.)

Comment: @MarkAmery I see what you are getting at, but at the same time "Here's something that won't work" isn't really an answer in my book (unless the question is phrased in a very curious manner)

Answer (score 25):

In a case like this, I'd recommend using a custom flag and stating something like

> This isn't an answer, but a response to this answer [link] and should be converted to a comment or removed.

That prevents any possible confusion from reviewers looking at the answer in the Low Quality Posts review queue, or moderators who may not have the full context here.

Also, if there's anything worth preserving in the answer, only moderators can convert these to comments on the other post. Low Quality Posts reviewers of "not an answer" flags can only vote to delete things.

If we have a flag like that, it's easy for us to pull up both posts, identify that this is a comment on one, and convert or delete in a quick action. A custom flag may linger for a little bit longer than a "not an answer" one, but that post has been around for a year anyway. That extra bit of information should make it more likely that the flag is handled the way you want.

Comment: I'd consider this already covered by the "not an answer" reason: *"This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. **It should possibly be [...], a comment, [...] or deleted altogether**."*

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Some of these comments-as-answers can look like answers at a first glance. The "not an answer" flag carries no context, so that can cause different people to miss what the original flagger saw. Also, if there's anything worth saving in the answer, only moderators can convert it to a comment. "not an answer" flags now feed into review, where deletion is the only option. If there's any possible confusion as to why something is flagged, or how it should be handled, I prefer to have that extra bit of context.

Comment: What are you going to do when the (not-really-an-)answer is long and requires multiple code examples to demonstrate why the answer it's criticising is wrong? I have an answer like this which perhaps will get flagged. You won't have the power to convert it to a comment due to length, but if you were to delete it you'd be destroying valuable information. It doesn't include an alternative approach beyond mentioning that there are already several *good* approaches given in other answers to the question and suggesting using them them. Should I expect to see my answer get nuked one day?

Comment: @MarkAmery - Even though such an answer isn't technically an answer, I almost always tend to preserve it. I'll mark "not an answer" flags as being helpful, but I won't delete the answer. If there's content worth saving, these rules aren't absolute. We can't lose sight of the forest for the trees.

Answer (score -17):

Yes, flag it ASAP. Otherwise people like this will continue to put people down.

Comment: The post in question doesn't put anyone down in any way. This answer on the other hand...